# How to determine the significance between females and males participants in a group?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have a group called smoking status of males and females. From 500 candidates, 120 females and 130 males smoke. What statistical test should I use to figure out if the number of smokers significantly differ between females and males?

Comment: perhaps `chisq.test`?

Comment: A chi-squared test is probably appropriate, but you do need to know also how many men and women in total there were so you can compete the 2x2 contingency table. One can also calculate an odds ratio and confidence interval to indicate direction of effect as well as precision of the estimate.

Comment: I know how many males and females are. In total there are 225 females and 275 males. Among females, 120 smoke, while among males 130 smoke. How can I test if they are significantly different in R? also how I create 2x2 contingency table? I am a beginner in statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a chisquare test. Then you first need to present your data as a contingency table. One way to do this in `R` is:

```
your_df <- data.frame(female=c(120,225-120),male=c(130,275-130))
rownames(your_df) <- c("smoke", "non-smoke")
your_df
          female male
smoke        120  130
non-smoke    105  145
```

Then use the chisquare test:

```
chisq.test(your_df)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  your_df
X-squared = 1.5838, df = 1, p-value = 0.2082
```

[For alternative (more modern, maybe better) methods see this paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-1/RJournal_2010-1_Fay.pdf).